# GADNativeAdView not showing Outlet on version 8.0 Google Mobile Ads SDK ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, google-mobile-ads

Before version 8.0 , that was work with **GADUnifiedNativeAdView** . but after updating to 8.0 that not showing outlet for **GADNativeAdView**. please see the attached screenshot below.

[image: This shows the class of the View]

[image: This shows no Outlet in Right Side.]

Please Help